# How to update database in live server from local database changes using code first mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

Actually my model classes changed also tables effected in local, so now i am going update my database to live but how to update local db changes into live.

Some buddy told me to use below command before update-database, but i did not taken update-database -script before executing update-database command

```
update-database -script
```

I do not want to stop my live website and i need to update my database changes and later i will upload application files.

Comment: Using the command you have will result in the generation of the script to perform the update if you direct it to your production schema.  Generating a script won’t actually run the script it allows you to review the impact of your update

Comment: Please help means best way to solve this issue i m very new in code first migration and mvc5. @PaulFarry

Comment: Try the command on a copy of the database in a safe place so you can experiment safely with the behaviour and understand how it works.

Comment: What will be the answer to solve my issue. @PaulFarry

Comment: See i have found one thing that i will bring live db into local and i will connect to brought db to my visual studio then i will write update-database -script -Force, then i am getting all scripts then i will execute into live db server. And later i will upload my changes files. @PaulFarry